# PHPWord export giving Corrupt Word File

Tags: php, xml, ms-word

I used the example code from PHPWord's site: http://phpword.codeplex.com/documentation
And when I try and open it with Word I get the error "The Office Open XML file test.docx cannot be opened because there are problems with the contents." and when I click "Details" It simply says "The file is corrupt and cannot be opened." It does let me repair it and open it, but that wouldn't be very user friendly... Here is the code I'm using:

```
// Create a new PHPWord Object
$PHPWord = new PHPWord();

// Every element you want to append to the word document is placed in a section. So you need a section:
$section = $PHPWord->createSection();

// After creating a section, you can append elements:
$section->addText('Hello world!');

// You can directly style your text by giving the addText function an array:
$section->addText('Hello world! I am formatted.', array('name'=>'Tahoma', 'size'=>16, 'bold'=>true));

// If you often need the same style again you can create a user defined style to the word document
// and give the addText function the name of the style>:
$PHPWord->addFontStyle('myOwnStyle', array('name'=>'Verdana', 'size'=>14, 'color'=>'1B2232'));
$section->addText('Hello world! I am formatted by a user defined style', 'myOwnStyle');

// You can also putthe appended element to local object an call functions like this:
$myTextElement = $section->addText('Hello World!');



header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-word');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="test.docx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
// At least write the document to webspace:
$objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

As you can see I did use php://output as the save there. Any ideas on how to get rid of the corruption. I did open the zip and saw that at the end of document.xml it appears there is blank line. Maybe that is causing it?

Thanks!

Comment: If you can open the zip, you should compare the differences between your version and Word's "repaired" version - this may give you a clue as to the problem, and you may have discovered a bug that needs reporting to the developers.

Comment: Watch out for any spaces (or other echoed characters) that your script might be inserting into the browser output

Comment: @DaveRandom THe difference I see is that document.xml has <w:p w:rsidR="007F0142" w:rsidRDefault="007F0142"/> in the repaired copy and it doesn't have line breaks.

Comment: @MarkBaker You can see what I am outputting above.

Comment: I can't see everything you're outputting, only what's being output between $PHPWord = new PHPWord(); and $objWriter->save('php://output'); - can you save to file rather than php://output and look for leading trailing spaces, error messages, BOM markers or whatever in that file

Comment: Also check whether there is any leading/trailing whitespace before/after your `<?php ?>` tags - and preferably lose the `?>` tag (if you have one)

Comment: This is the entire file. There are no spaces or extra code...does it work the same for you?

Comment: I'm not sure how to get it to save on the server, permission issues.

Comment: Oh and no trailing ?> just kill it off after output'); no space or new line. and there is a <? but no space or line before it.

Answer (score 17):

Any Text you add should not contain HTML characters. Convert all applicable characters to HTML entities for example if you have to add the following "Me & my Code" first do this:

```
$Text_to_Add = htmlentities("Me & my Code");
$section->addText($Text_to_Add);
```

Use the Builtin function to save the file. docx files are zip files (you can open them in winrar or winzip) so you should not use php://output

```
$objWriter->save('helloWorld.docx');    
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=helloWorld.docx");
header("Content-Type: application/docx");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
```

This way the file will be created and then downloaded by user.

Side Note: docx files are actually XML files. So any xml reserve character will corrupt the file. A workaround is to convert your text as following

```
function xmlEntities($str)
{
    $xml = array('&#34;','&#38;','&#38;','&#60;','&#62;','&#160;','&#161;','&#162;','&#163;','&#164;','&#165;','&#166;','&#167;','&#168;','&#169;','&#170;','&#171;','&#172;','&#173;','&#174;','&#175;','&#176;','&#177;','&#178;','&#179;','&#180;','&#181;','&#182;','&#183;','&#184;','&#185;','&#186;','&#187;','&#188;','&#189;','&#190;','&#191;','&#192;','&#193;','&#194;','&#195;','&#196;','&#197;','&#198;','&#199;','&#200;','&#201;','&#202;','&#203;','&#204;','&#205;','&#206;','&#207;','&#208;','&#209;','&#210;','&#211;','&#212;','&#213;','&#214;','&#215;','&#216;','&#217;','&#218;','&#219;','&#220;','&#221;','&#222;','&#223;','&#224;','&#225;','&#226;','&#227;','&#228;','&#229;','&#230;','&#231;','&#232;','&#233;','&#234;','&#235;','&#236;','&#237;','&#238;','&#239;','&#240;','&#241;','&#242;','&#243;','&#244;','&#245;','&#246;','&#247;','&#248;','&#249;','&#250;','&#251;','&#252;','&#253;','&#254;','&#255;');
    $html = array('&quot;','&amp;','&amp;','&lt;','&gt;','&nbsp;','&iexcl;','&cent;','&pound;','&curren;','&yen;','&brvbar;','&sect;','&uml;','&copy;','&ordf;','&laquo;','&not;','&shy;','&reg;','&macr;','&deg;','&plusmn;','&sup2;','&sup3;','&acute;','&micro;','&para;','&middot;','&cedil;','&sup1;','&ordm;','&raquo;','&frac14;','&frac12;','&frac34;','&iquest;','&Agrave;','&Aacute;','&Acirc;','&Atilde;','&Auml;','&Aring;','&AElig;','&Ccedil;','&Egrave;','&Eacute;','&Ecirc;','&Euml;','&Igrave;','&Iacute;','&Icirc;','&Iuml;','&ETH;','&Ntilde;','&Ograve;','&Oacute;','&Ocirc;','&Otilde;','&Ouml;','&times;','&Oslash;','&Ugrave;','&Uacute;','&Ucirc;','&Uuml;','&Yacute;','&THORN;','&szlig;','&agrave;','&aacute;','&acirc;','&atilde;','&auml;','&aring;','&aelig;','&ccedil;','&egrave;','&eacute;','&ecirc;','&euml;','&igrave;','&iacute;','&icirc;','&iuml;','&eth;','&ntilde;','&ograve;','&oacute;','&ocirc;','&otilde;','&ouml;','&divide;','&oslash;','&ugrave;','&uacute;','&ucirc;','&uuml;','&yacute;','&thorn;','&yuml;');
    $str = str_replace($html,$xml,$str);
    $str = str_ireplace($html,$xml,$str);
    return $str;
}


$Text_to_Add = htmlentities("Me & my Code");
$Test_to_Add_XML_Cleaned = xmlEntities($Text_to_Add);
$section->addText($Test_to_Add_XML_Cleaned);
```

Comment: still getting an invalid file. It does download though.

Comment: Want me to link to the created file? Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/Jf1pshzE

Comment: @oneadvent docx files are xml files so you should also try not to add html characters in your text. Better to use the following function to convert htmlentities to xmlentities

Comment: I can confirm that xmlEntities works with the setValue function that's in the TemplateProcessor. Thanks @UsmanShaukat!

Comment: @cbloss793 glad i can help

Answer (score 17):

Just add ob_clean(); before output it!

```
ob_clean();
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

This will clean you'r output, and now you are safe to generate docx file :)

Answer (score 13):

I know this is an old question but I had the exact same problem and just found the easiest solution of all. The problem I had is that I'm using Symfony, and that when generating the file, I had to edit the file with Notepad++ to see that there were error messages after the content, saying that the controller needed a Response().

So I ended up putting `exit;` just after the `->save()`, and it worked fine.

Comment: I'm using Yii2 and in versions <= 2.0.13 it works ok but after upgrading Yii2 just works this way you refer putting `exit;` just after the `->save()`

Answer (score 4):

1. Add `setCompatibility()` before `createWriter()`

   ```
   \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setCompatibility(false);
   ```
2. Add `exit;` after the `save()`

   ```
   // XML Writer compatibility
   \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setCompatibility(false);

   // Saving the document as OOXML file...
   $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
   ob_clean();
   $objWriter->save('php://output');

   exit;
   ```

Answer (score 4):

While using **PHPWord** `TemplateProcessor` I faced the same issue.

By enabling `setOutputEscapingEnabled` from `PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings` fixes the issue for me.

```
PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setOutputEscapingEnabled(true);  
$templateProcessor->saveAs($filepath);
```

As reported by [Māris Kiseļovs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/386348/m%C4%81ris-kise%C4%BCovs)

> But You had to call `setOutputEscapingEnabled` before replacing values
> in template document

Comment: This worked for me but I had to call setOutputEscapingEnabled before replacing values in template document.

Comment: updated you comment in answer

Comment: By doing so the final document will content XML tags

Comment: Worked for me and I'm not using TemplateProcessor

Answer (score 1):

Above Answers are great.

But for me I applied all above solutions but still I was getting issue. Finally I got solution by debugging each line.

Here are my findings.

If you add Row `$phpWord->addRow()`; without any line content after that you will also get Corrupt Word File issue.

```
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
$phpWord->setDefaultParagraphStyle(array('space' => array('line' =>10)));
$section = $phpWord->addSection(['marginLeft' => 600, 'marginRight' => 600]);
$textrun = $section->addTextRun();
$table_shipment_Detail = $section->addTable(); 
$table_shipment_Detail->addRow();

if($consignee->iec_no != ""){
   $table_shipment_Detail->addCell(800)->addText("IEC:".$consignee->iec_no);
}
if($consignee->gst_no != ""){
   $table_shipment_Detail->addCell(800)->addText("GST:".$consignee->gst_no);
}
if($consignee->tax_id != ""){
   $table_shipment_Detail->addCell(1500)->addText("TAX ID:".$consignee->tax_id);
}
```

If you see above example, I have use `$table_shipment_Detail->addRow();` but `$consignee->iec_no, $consignee->tax_id, $consignee->tax_id` are blank so when doc created it throws Corrupt Word File issue.

so I had to replace above code with following snippet.

```
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
$phpWord->setDefaultParagraphStyle(array('space' => array('line' =>10)));
$section = $phpWord->addSection(['marginLeft' => 600, 'marginRight' => 600]);
$textrun = $section->addTextRun();
$table_shipment_Detail = $section->addTable(); 
if($consignee->iec_no != "" || $consignee->gst_no != "" || $consignee->tax_id != ""){
    $table_shipment_Detail->addRow();
}
    
if($consignee->iec_no != ""){
     $table_shipment_Detail->addCell(800)->addText("IEC:".$consignee->iec_no);
}
if($consignee->gst_no != ""){
     $table_shipment_Detail->addCell(800)->addText("GST:".$consignee->gst_no);
}
if($consignee->tax_id != ""){
     $table_shipment_Detail->addCell(1500)->addText("TAX ID:".$consignee->tax_id);
}
```

I hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

```
     $h2d_file_uri = tempnam('', 'htd');
    //exit($h2d_file_uri);
    $objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($php_Word, 'Word2007');
    $objWriter->save($h2d_file_uri);


    // Download the file:
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Disposition:    attachment;filename=BMP_QuotationNo_'.$html[0['quoteno'].'.docx');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($h2d_file_uri));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    $status = readfile($h2d_file_uri);
    unlink($h2d_file_uri);
    exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me

```
    $phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();

$section = $phpWord->addSection(
  array('paperSize' => 'Legal', 'marginLeft' => 2834.645669291, 'marginRight' => 1417.322834646, 'marginTop' => 2834.645669291, 'marginBottom' => 1417.322834646)
);
//$html = $_POST['description'];
$html = $_POST['description'];


\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html::addHtml($section, $html, false, false);

// Save file
// Saving the document as OOXML file...
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
//$objWriter->save('test.docx');


  $temp_file_uri = tempnam('', 'xyz');
  $objWriter->save($temp_file_uri);
 //download code
  header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
  header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=helloWorld.docx');
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
  header('Expires: 0');
  header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($temp_file_uri));
  readfile($temp_file_uri);
  unlink($temp_file_uri); // deletes the temporary file
  exit;
```

Comment: hi, It Work for me but i want to save file as well in a specified directory..

Answer (score 0):

I did try all the methods but got errors.
This fixed it.
I was using the .PHP file under the

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
...........
<body>
<?PHP CODE ?>
</body>
</html>
```
The HTML encoding here was giving problems, once I removed all HTML HEAD and BODY  and DOCTYPE TAGS and left pre PHP Code 
```
<?PHP  .... ?>
```
Worked like a charm !!!
Cheers
````